# Generate row numbers in SQL from Interbase

Tags: sql, interbase

Is this possible from Interbase ?
For example like in this [link](http://www.openwinforms.com/row_number_to_sql_select.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generator. Create it

```
CREATE GENERATOR g_rowno;
```

And then use like this

```
SELECT GEN_ID(g_rowno, 1), field1, field2, ... FROM your_table
```

But it will work only if there is no concurrent executions of the same query.

In Firebird you can use EXECUTE BLOCK construction for processing every row and
adding row number before passing it to the client application.